# Why does an Admob banner ad doesn't show to me? [Android, libGDX]

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I have a problem:

I've installed an Admob ad banner in my app and when I'm using this command to builder:

```
builder.addTestDevice(
            "0277F42DBB49E3FD56F9EFFE3C4380B4"
)
```

Everything works (I mean, I see banner with similar text "congrats, bla-bla-bla, etc".

But.

In published game, which of course has disabled this line (addTestDevice) it doesn't show.

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hypeofpipe.westernshooter"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.02">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.hypeofpipe.westernshooter.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

**AndroidLauncher.java**

```
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication
            implements UrlOpener, AdHandler {

    protected AdView adView;
    private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
    private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

    Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case SHOW_ADS:
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case HIDE_ADS:
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        adView = new AdView(this);
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        View gameView = initializeForView(new MainClass(this, this), config);

        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                int visibility = adView.getVisibility();
                adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
                adView.setVisibility(visibility);
                AudioManager.getInstance().playSound(
                        AudioManager.getInstance().shot_missed
                );
            }
        });
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(*here goes my unitid from admob*);

        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        layout.addView(gameView);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);
        adView.loadAd(builder.build());

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    public void openURL(String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
    }
    }
```

**MainClass.java**

```
    public class MainClass extends Game {

    public static UrlOpener urlOpener;
    public static AdHandler adHandler;

    public MainClass(UrlOpener urlOpener,
                     AdHandler adHandler)
    {
        this.urlOpener = urlOpener;
        this.adHandler = adHandler;
        adHandler.showAds(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        Assets.getInstance().load();
        Assets.getInstance().assetManager.finishLoading();
        setScreen(new ScreenModified(this));
    }

}
```

Some fragment from code, where ads are called to show.

```
MainClass.adHandler.showAds(true);
```

Also, I have 0 requests from mine app.

[image: Admob]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ads working fine with `addTestDevice(XXX)` but not getting live Ads.

**Follow these steps :**

1. Wait for some times/hours or a day.
2. If you're able to load/get test ads but not live ads, It sounds like an issue with your AdMob account.
3. After waiting still having problem then you need to cross check Ad unit Id and AppId from AdMob account.
4. Make sure that you properly set up a payment system and/or verified your PIN? If they are not done, then live ads would not be served from your account.
5. Still problem now you need to post your problem in this [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo) for assistance.

Comment: Yeah, "Payments" tab wasn't configured at all. But, I've configured it and I cannot add a payment method, because:
"You don't need a payment method until your earnings threshold has been reached". 

I will wait for tomorrow and then give some feedback, if problem will be fixed.

Comment: Yeap, I'v made a step 4, because I don't had payment methods and step 1 is good as well. Thank you!